# MySQL Meteor error :"bad formatting in HTML template" after installing mysql-live-select

Tags: mysql, meteor, npm

I have been trying to integrate mysql with meteor.

i installed the mysql-live-select package in the meteor app using the command

```
npm install mysql
```

which was successful. I followed the instructions on https://github.com/numtel/mysql-live-select.

After running the meteor app  I got the following error

```
While building the application:
node_modules/mysql-live-select/node_modules/mysql/node_modules/bignumber.js/doc/API.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets
<!DOCTYPE html> for you)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I then removed DOCTYPE html from the api.hmtl file which gave me the folllowing error on running the meteor app again.

```
While building the application:
node_modules/mysql-live-select/node_modules/mysql/node_modules/bignumber.js/doc/API.html:2: bad formatting in HTML template

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I had followed the same steps on another ubuntu machine 2 days back and it was working fine. However when I tried to integrate MySQL and Meteor today I got the above error on both the ubuntu machines.

What could be the reason for this since the HTML file is the one made from installing the mysql-live-select package? How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Meteor package, you have to use https://github.com/numtel/meteor-mysql instead.
The error is that it tries to put all the HTML documentation in node.js package into a meteor templates.